# How to say about your blood pressure?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following expressions is more correct or exposes a better English structure or grammar?

> - My blood pressure is low/high.
> - I suffer from/have low/high blood pressure?

After some Googling I found both of them but I couldn't find out which of them is better or more correct grammatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both (all six?) of them are correct. It depends on context.

The first one means that you are referring to that particular instant of time.

The second one can be relaxed over a longer time frame (like a month, a year or a week).

Comment: So they do not mean a same thing! Important point which I didn't know.

Comment: But I would drop the **a** from the second. *I suffer from high blood pressure.*  not *from **a** high blood pressure*.  And *I have high blood pressure* is probably the most commonly uttered form.

Answer (score 2):

Any of these are correct:

> My blood pressure is low
>
> I have high blood pressure
>
> I suffer **from** low blood pressure

If you wanted to indicate that your blood pressure was low at the instant that you were speaking I would use the first sentence---the *is* implies "right now". If you meant it in a more general sense I would use the third.